# watchOS does not enter ComplicationController

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I want to develop a simple complication as my first watchOS project. 
I've set everything up as the screenshot shows:

[image: set up of data source class]

But When I set a breakpoint inside `ComplicationController.swift`, it will not be called. Therefore, my complication does not fill with any data I supply. I set a breakpoint to all implemented methods (e.g. `getLocalizableSampleTemplate`) in that class, but the code is just running and the complication does not fill with the supplied data.

What am I doing wrong?
My class conforms to `CLKComplicationDataSource` (I left all the default implementation).

[image: ComplicationController]

Comment: Can you show where in ComplicationController.swift you are putting the breakpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if I add `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).` in front of the data source class inside the complication configuration.

[image]